# Is ApplicationSettings working properly on emulator?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this simple xaml page to collect user information:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,36,0,0" Text="Enter your birth year :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312" FontSize="32" />
        <TextBox FontSize="32"  Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,19,0,0" Name="birthyear" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,112,0,0" Name="birthyear_message" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" />            
        <TextBlock FontSize="32" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,283,0,0" Text="Enter your post code :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312" />
        <TextBox FontSize="32" TextAlignment="Center" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,268,0,0" Name="postcode" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" />
        <TextBlock Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,356,0,0" Name="postcode_message" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,441,0,0" Name="cancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="cancel_Click" />
        <Button Content="Save" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,441,0,0" Name="save" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="save_Click" />             
</Grid>
```

My code behind is like this:

```
//Set and display user a set of default values if user is accessing page for first time else retrieve data from the settings
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (settings.Contains("birthyear"))
            birthyear.Text = settings["birthyear"].ToString();
        else
        {                
            birthyear.Text = (DateTime.Now.Year - 25).ToString();
            settings.Add("birthyear", birthyear.Text);
        }

        if (settings.Contains("postcode"))
            birthyear.Text = settings["postcode"].ToString();
        else
        {
            postcode.Text = "10044";
            settings.Add("postcode", postcode.Text);
        }
    }

private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    //ignore error conditions for the time being!    
    settings.Remove("birthyear");
    settings.Add("birthyear", birthyear.Text);

    settings.Remove("postcode");
    settings.Add("postcode", postcode.Text);

    settings.Save();

    //Navigate to the same page to validate values entered by user is saved
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Now coming to the problem. When the user navigates for the first time, the default values of 1986 and 10044 are shown. Now I edit the values, say 1999 and 65222 and select Save. What happens now is that the birthyear is showing 65222 and postcode is showing blank. What is the problem?

Update:
When I try to retrieve the values in the Intermediate Window in VS, the new values are displayed properly. I am guessing it is saving properly but is having problems while retrieving/displaying it

Comment: I couldn't be more stupid than this ... I was displaying the wrong value

if (settings.Contains("postcode"))
            birthyear.Text = settings["postcode"].ToString();

it should have been postcode.Text

Answer (score 1):

You could try changeing the value instead, and do

```
settings["birthyear"] = birthyear.Text;
settings["postcode"] = postcode.Text;
```

And maybe also try casting your settings as type IsolatedStorageSettings.

EDIT:

```
settings.Remove("birthyear");
settings.Add("birthyear", birthyear.Text);

settings.Remove("postcode");
settings.Add("postcode", postcode.Text);

settings.Save();
```

Becomes:

```
settings["birthyear"] = birthyear.Text;
settings["postcode"] = postcode.Text;
```

Comment: do you mean changing the values while saving or retrieving?

Comment: sorry for wasting ur time ... i did a silly mistake ... thanks anyways for looking at it instantly